# How to check if object is null?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application which retrieves images from the web. In case the image cannot be retrieved another local image should be used.

While trying to execute the following lines:

```
Drawable drawable = Common.getDrawableFromUrl(this, product.getMapPath());
if (drawable.equals(null)) {
  drawable = getRandomDrawable();
}
```

The line if(drawable.equals(null)) throws an exception if drawable is null.

Does anyone know how should the value of drawable be checked in order not to throw an exception in case it is null and retrieve the local image (execute `drawable = getRandomDrawable()`)?

Comment: Use *if(drawable==null)* Calling any method on a NULL object is a NullPointerException.

Comment: Why don't you write a usual answer instead of a comment, diciu?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Do not edit the code in a question in a way that defeats the purpose of the question!

Comment: @Gilles Read my editorial comment, I made the code more readable.

Comment: @JaredBurrows No, your edit was not a “formatting” change. You changed non-working code which was the object of the question, into working code which made the question moot.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I had to revert (some of) your changes - you changed it from `drawable.equals(null)` to `isNull(drawable)` - I assume you copied from your first (formatting only) edit on Eddie B's answer. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Giles `isNull(drawable)` won't compile, because there is no `isNull` defined in the context of the question.

Comment: @stuXnet That's perfectly fine. Good question just needed reformatting.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Edited Java 8 Solution:**

```
final Drawable drawable = 
    Optional.ofNullable(Common.getDrawableFromUrl(this, product.getMapPath()))
        .orElseGet(() -> getRandomDrawable());
```

You can declare `drawable` `final` in this case.

As Chasmo pointed out, Android doesn't support Java 8 at the moment. So this solution is only possible in other contexts.

Comment: Probably not a good idea - you're going back to Fortran 60  where both sides of the conditional are evaluated, then only one gets used. This is bad if the unused branch has any computation, which is true most the time, so it isn't a generally useful method. I'd move the condition to the `Common` class, and allow you to supply a fallback URL, and keep the responsibilities together.

Comment: The example is now completely rewritten in Java 8, so my solution suffers no longer from useless evaluations (as @PeteKirkham pointed out in my original solution).

Comment: Android does not support Java 8. It only supports up to Java 7 (if you have kitkat) and still it doesn't have invokedynamic, only the new syntax sugar. Beside that, `Optional.of` implies, that the value is not null, and therefore the `orElseGet` is unnecessary. You should use `Optional.ofNullable` in this case.

Answer (score 190):

```
Drawable drawable = Common.getDrawableFromUrl(this, product.getMapPath());
if (drawable == null) {
    drawable = getRandomDrawable();
}
```

The `equals()` method checks for *value* equality, which means that it compares the *contents* of two objects. Since `null` is not an object, this crashes when trying to compare the contents of your object to the contents of `null`.

The `==` operator checks for *reference* equality, which means that it looks whether the two objects are actually the *very same object*. This does not require the objects to actually exist; two nonexistent objects (`null` references) are also equal.

Comment: I want to add a very valuable tip: If you have strings or constants to compare, *always* put them first in the equals clause.

(if ("coyote".equals(myDogString))) is much better than 

(if (myDogString.equals("coyote")))  

because in the second case myDogString may be null and throws an NPE while in the first case it doesn't matter if myDogString is null.

Comment: Known as a Yoda condition: "if a coyote, the dog is..."

Comment: I would also like to add, that since Java 7 there is an Objects.equals() method, that let's you not care about Yoda syntax

Answer (score 25):

I use this approach:

```
if (null == drawable) {
  //do stuff
} else {
  //other things
}
```

This way I find improves the readability of the line - as I read quickly through a source file I can see it's a null check.

With regards to why you can't call `.equals()` on an object which may be `null`; if the object reference you have (namely 'drawable') **is** in fact `null`, it doesn't point to an object on the heap. This means there's no object on the heap on which the call to `equals()` can succeed.

Best of luck!

Comment: I too prefer the if(<constant> == <variable>) construct as a way to protect myself from accidental assignment.

Answer (score 7):

`if (yourObject instanceof yourClassName)` will evaluate to `false` if `yourObject` is `null`.

Answer (score 7):

DIY

```
private boolean isNull(Object obj) {
    return obj == null;
}
```

---

```
Drawable drawable = Common.getDrawableFromUrl(this, product.getMapPath());
if (isNull(drawable)) {
    drawable = getRandomDrawable();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
drawable.equals(null)
```

The above line calls the "equals(...)" method on the drawable object.

So, when drawable is not null and it is a real object, then all goes well as calling the "equals(null)" method will return "false"

But when "drawable" is null, then it means calling the "equals(...)" method on null object, means calling a method on an object that doesn't exist so it throws "NullPointerException"

To check whether an object exists and it is not null, use the following

```
if(drawable == null) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

In above condition, we are checking that the reference variable "drawable" is null or contains some value (reference to its object) so it won't throw exception in case drawable is null as checking

```
null == null
```

is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use [google guava libs](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) to handle is-null-check (deamon's update)

```
Drawable drawable = Optional.of(Common.getDrawableFromUrl(this, product.getMapPath())).or(getRandomDrawable());
```

Comment: Better use Java 8 `Optional` today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Objects.isNull(Object)`

Answer (score -3):

It's probably slightly more efficient to catch a NullPointerException. The above methods mean that the runtime is checking for null pointers twice.

Comment: Where is the double check in `if x == null` solution?

Comment: After the if statement, the runtime will check again for a null pointer when the object is used. I don't know whether or not this is optimised by the compiler, though.

Comment: This goes against conventional wisdom, using exceptions as control flow.

Comment: Exceptions are very expensive, since they need to create a whole stacktrace.